# Help With Server Side App - WinForms - Creating Jpegs

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, jpeg

I have a winforms app that when it starts, it opens a url in a webbrowser control and takes a snapshot of that saving it to a jpeg on the server.  It works great when I run the app by double clicking it, but if I fire it from my asp.net generic handler with Process.start I see the process appear in Task Manager but I do not get any images saved.  Is is possible for me to fire a winforms app and get it operate normally from my generic handler page?

Comment: Sounds like a login issue. The asp.net generic handler isn't logged in as you, and likely doesn't have a UI. It's not going to work the way you expect if you want to launch a GUI app and take a screenshot of the UI when there isn't one.

What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to do it.

Comment: I have an application that involves generating a jpeg from text/images and shapes.  Right now this process is done client side and uploaded, but if I could do it server side it would be simpler.  What I think I will ultimately do is have my screenshot maker running on the server all the time and have it create the images as the requests come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up abandoning this path and using a process running on the server